# CSS rules in different order leads to different results

Tags: css, background, mask

I just took a look on CSS background-clip. Its a way to mask text with an image. (or the other way round? ^^). Anyway, i thought the order of statements in CSS doesn't effect the result, but with background clip it does.

The CSS for this effect looks like this usually:

```
.text{
    color: transparent;
    background: url(pic.ending);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

So, this is the first `<p>` in the fiddle below.
But when I change the order of this to following:

```
.text_wrong{
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    background: url(pic.ending);
}
```

It doesn't work. The text isn't masked, the background takes place in the hole `<p>`. So the error occurs when background clip is before background, right?

Why? Do you have any idea? Sorry for my bad English. (Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6yE7/9/).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background` is the shorthand notation for the background properties. This will overwrite all other background rules made earlier. Even though `-webkit-background-clip` has a vendor prefix it is still a background property. In your second example it gets overwritten when you set the background properties with the shorthand notation.

To make your example work you can use `background-image` instead of `background`.

**Example**

```
/* sets a single property */
background-color: red;
/* overwrites all single properties */
background: no-repeat;
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/zVmum/)

Answer (score 1):

This is called Cascading and the ulimate goal of CSS is to represent those items that are declared last in the cascade.

For instance, lets assume the below to be your CSS declaration in stylesheets.

```
div{height:15px;}

div{height:30px;}

div{height:20px;}
```

So the div will take the height to be `20px` as this is the last declared rule and it will override all the other rules declared earlier.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: -1 because, while this isn't wrong, it's not wholly relevant. @insertusernamehere's answer addresses what's actually happening when the `background` shortcut is used. This also risks over-simplifying the cascade: it's worth [reading this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Cascading_and_inheritance) to get a full grasp of what's going on. This isn't an example of the cascade, just over-riding previously declared styles.

Comment: Thnx - @CherryFlavourPez for the mention. But the OP has specifically laid his code where he has specifically changed the cascade of the attribute rules and that is causing him to get the issue. So I shall stick to my answer and would be willing to rectify if it genuinely deserves rectification.

Comment: But the salient point is *not* that writing `div{height:15px;}` followed by `div{height:20px;}` results in a `div` that's 20px high (which is obvious even to someone with little-to-no CSS knowledge). Rather, that certain shorthand properties will over-ride previously declared styles in a much less transparent way (`background` being the obvious example, but there are others such as `font`).

Comment: Agreed - @CherryFlavourPez OP had the change in the order of his cascade that did not made his thing worked correctly, so cascade was the thing that he had to keep, but at the same time, certain CSS properties as you mentioned above needs to be declared in a much transparent manner for things to work accurately :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the w3c specs the value `text` for `background-clip` is not a listed value in the specs. Therefor support might be buggy!

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#background-clip

> Determines the background painting area, which determines the area
>   within which the background is painted. The syntax of the property is
>   given with
>
> = border-box | padding-box | content-box